# IndentationError: expected an indented block Can someone help me

Tags: python, syntax-error

Why do I get `IndentationError: expected an indented block` from this code:

```
def downloadVideo():

    x = entry.get()

    logging.debug(x + " - Done")
    ydl_opts = {} --------------------------------------- I get error here
    with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl:
    ydl.download([x])
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to indent this line:

```
ydl.download([x])
```

So the resulting code should be something like:

```
x = entry.get()

logging.debug(x + " - Done")
ydl_opts = {}
with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl:
    ydl.download([x])
```

Python requires indentation rather than curly braces like other programming languages you may be used to.